# Case Assignment Rule Not firing

Tags: case, assignment-rules

Another tedious question I fear!

My case assignment rule has the following rules:

1. High Priority Queue: (Case Origin = Facebook)  OR (case origin = Twitter)
2. High Priority Queue: (Case Subject contains "Voicemail")
3. Customer Services Queue: (Case Status = New).

It all seems so logical to me, I want social and voicemail cases to go into the High Priority queue which is routed with a higher priority through Omni.  I want the rest to go to the customer services queue which is the "normal routing".

The above works for most cases, emails etc are all put into #3 correctly.  Voicemails are all picked up as expected in #2.

However social cases aren't picked up by #1 (and under Social Business Rules I have enabled "Apply case assignment rules to case routing") and secondly live chat cases (created by "System" or "Automated Process") simply don't meet any of the criteria (nothing in their case history).

I am currently trialling a fourth rule entry for picking up cases owned by system/automated process but I don't have high hopes.

Can anyone advise why social/chat cases don't trigger the case assignments?

Comment: Is the automation that assigns Case Origin firing before assignment? That could be the issue.

Comment: But I can't think what that is, is it part of the social service and/or the chat api that kicks in after the normal execution order?  I think Facebook/twitter cases are working now, I deactivated a related workflow rule that had an owner field update (ofc).  The chat cases are far busier and I have yet to figure those out.